# converting raster data to factor in R

Tags: r, r-raster

I have imported a raster file into R - it is categorical, with two values, 0 and 1. 
I need to have it stored as a factor.

I have tried the following:

```
#as.factor when importing 
mydata.factor <- as.factor(raster("mydata.tif"))

#or import first then try converting
mydata <- raster(mydata.tif)
mydata.factor <- as.factor(mydata)

#or call just values 
mydata <- raster(mydata.tif)
mydata$values <- as.factor(mydata$values)

#or based on the example in the Raster package, something like this
mydata <- raster(mydata.tif)
mydata.factor <- as.factor(mydata)
mydata.factorlevels <- levels(mydata.factors)[[1]]
```

I can't quite get what I want, which is a layer that when called into another function (the joincount.multi function in package spdedp) is recognized as a factor. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution which is simply to 1. convert to points (stored as matrix) then 2. convert to dataframe, then 3. Convert variable of interest to factor.

```
mydatasp <- rasterToPoints(mydata)
mydatadf <- as.data.frame(mydatasp)
mydatadf$variable <- as.factor(mydatadf$variable)
```

I don't know of a way to do this that keeps the data as a raster.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played much with `ratify` and `as.factor` but they might be useful:
https://web.archive.org/web/20151109014439/http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/asFactor